# Слайдер, как у ламода

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, очень нужен слайдер, как на сайте lamoda(.)ru, который на главной стоит в центре - большой квадрат размером 590 на 508 пикселей.

Пробовал вытащить его, а он ни в какую не работает.

Итак, что мы имеем:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="//www.lamoda.ru/tstatic/js/libs.js?v=923658779c7df00e14c8d1dda07c4c56"></script>

<!-- TO DO marketing_pxls_data: cms_data -->

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src=""//lmcdn.ru/tstatic/js/libs/json2.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="//www.lamoda.ru/tstatic/js/additional/pixels.js?v=923658779c7df00e14c8d1dda07c4c56"></script>

<script src="//www.lamoda.ru/tstatic/js/additional/main-pixels.js?v=923658779c7df00e14c8d1dda07c4c56"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.lamoda.ru/tstatic/js/lamoda.js?v=923658779c7df00e14c8d1dda07c4c56"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.lamoda.ru/tstatic/js/multifilter.js?v=923658779c7df00e14c8d1dda07c4c56"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="b-sliders">
    <style type="text/css">
        .b-sliders {border: solid 1px #CCC; margin: 0 0 12px 12px; float: left; width: 590px;}
        .mediaplex_slider {width: 590px; height: 508px; overflow: hidden; float: right; position: relative;}
        .mediaplex_slider .prev,
        .mediaplex_slider .next {width: 33px; height: 38px; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -19px; cursor: pointer; z-index: 5;}
        .mediaplex_slider .prev {left: -1px;}
        .mediaplex_slider .next {right: -1px;}

        .mediaplex_slider .slides_container {width: 590px; height: 508px; display: none;}
        .mediaplex_slider .slides_container div {width: 590px; height: 508px; display: block;}

        .mediaplex_slider .pgn {list-style: none; position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 5px; z-index: 5;}
        .mediaplex_slider .pgn li {background: #505050; color: #000; display: block; min-width: 16px; margin-right: 4px; float: left; text-align: center;}
        .mediaplex_slider .pgn li a {display: block; color: #fff;}
        .mediaplex_slider .pgn li.current {background: #fff; color: #505050;}
        .mediaplex_slider .pgn li.current a {color: #505050;}

        .cms-segment-sport .mediaplex_slider .pgn li {background-color: #fff;}
        .cms-segment-sport .mediaplex_slider .pgn li.current {background-color: #264c7b;}
        .cms-segment-sport .mediaplex_slider .pgn li a {color: #264c7b;}
        .cms-segment-sport .mediaplex_slider .pgn li.current a {color: #fff;}
    </style>
    <div id="slides" class="mediaplex_slider">
        <div id="slides_container" class="slides_container"></div>
        <a class="prev" href="#"></a>
        <a class="next" href="#"></a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var timestamp = new Date().getTime(),
                    dataLink = [
                        'http://ad-emea.doubleclick.net/adj/N6705.309581.LAMODA.RU1/B5807564.309;sz=590x508;ord='+timestamp+'?',
                        'http://ad-emea.doubleclick.net/adj/N6705.309581.LAMODA.RU1/B5807564.310;sz=590x508;ord='+timestamp+'?',
                        'http://ad-emea.doubleclick.net/adj/N6705.309581.LAMODA.RU1/B5807564.308;sz=590x508;ord='+timestamp+'?'
                    ],
                    affiliate_base = $.cookie('affiliate_base') || '',
                    urlParams =  $.url().param(),
                    urlContainsMnogoRu = (urlParams.utm_source && urlParams.utm_source === 'mnogo_ru') ||
                                         (urlParams.utm_campaign && urlParams.utm_campaign === 'mnogo_ru');

            /*if (urlContainsMnogoRu || affiliate_base) {
                var  mnogoCookie = affiliate_base.split(';');
                if (urlContainsMnogoRu || mnogoCookie[2] == "mnogo_ru" || mnogoCookie[3] == "mnogo_ru") {

                    dataLink.splice(0,0,'<div><a href="/rasprodazha/"><img src="//lmcdn.ru/media/banner/HP_mnogo_MZ.jpg" alt="mnogo.ru" /></a></div>');
                }
            }*/

            $(function(){
                $('#slides_container').bannerWriter({
                    data: dataLink,
                    onComplete: function(element){
                        element.find('a').prop('target','_self');
                        element.parent().slides({
                            play: 5000,
                            pause: 2500,
                            paginationClass: 'pgn',
                            generateNextPrev: true,
                            hoverPause: true
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

        })();

    </script>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы слайдер заработал? А то ни в какую не хочет, а я далеко не спец в javascript`e.

Answer (score 3):

Есть хороший слайдер nivoslider

Comment: ок, спасибо, действительно nivoslider очень практичный, разобрался как сделать нужное. Еще раз большое всем спасибо)))

Comment: Желательно более детально отвечать на вопросы

Answer (score 3):

Работает:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.lamoda.ru/tstatic/css/style.css?v=923658779c7df00e14c8d1dda07c4c56" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="//www.lamoda.ru/tstatic/js/libs.js?v=923658779c7df00e14c8d1dda07c4c56"></script>
</head>

<body class=" cms-segment-basic cms-gender-common new-design">
<div class="b-sliders">

    <style type="text/css">
        .b-sliders {border: solid 1px #CCC; margin: 0 0 12px 12px; float: left; width: 590px;}
        .mediaplex_slider {width: 590px; height: 508px; overflow: hidden; float: right; position: relative;}
        .mediaplex_slider .prev,
        .mediaplex_slider .next {width: 33px; height: 38px; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -19px; cursor: pointer; z-index: 5;}
        .mediaplex_slider .prev {left: -1px;}
        .mediaplex_slider .next {right: -1px;}

        .mediaplex_slider .slides_container {width: 590px; height: 508px; display: none;}
        .mediaplex_slider .slides_container div {width: 590px; height: 508px; display: block;}

        .mediaplex_slider .pgn {list-style: none; position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 5px; z-index: 5;}
        .mediaplex_slider .pgn li {background: #505050; color: #000; display: block; min-width: 16px; margin-right: 4px; float: left; text-align: center;}
        .mediaplex_slider .pgn li a {display: block; color: #fff;}
        .mediaplex_slider .pgn li.current {background: #fff; color: #505050;}
        .mediaplex_slider .pgn li.current a {color: #505050;}

        .cms-segment-sport .mediaplex_slider .pgn li {background-color: #fff;}
        .cms-segment-sport .mediaplex_slider .pgn li.current {background-color: #264c7b;}
        .cms-segment-sport .mediaplex_slider .pgn li a {color: #264c7b;}
        .cms-segment-sport .mediaplex_slider .pgn li.current a {color: #fff;}

.mediaplex_slider .next,
.mediaplex_slider .prev {
    background: transparent url('//lmcdn.ru/media/pages/header/sprite-header_13.png') no-repeat;
}
.mediaplex_slider .next:hover {background-position: 0 -105px; width: 33px; height: 38px;}
.mediaplex_slider .next {background-position: 0 -143px; width: 33px; height: 38px;}
.mediaplex_slider .prev:hover {background-position: 0 -181px; width: 33px; height: 38px;}
.mediaplex_slider .prev {background-position: 0 -219px; width: 33px; height: 38px;}

    </style>
    <div id="slides" class="mediaplex_slider">
        <div id="slides_container" class="slides_container"></div>
        <a class="prev" href="#"></a>
        <a class="next" href="#"></a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var timestamp = dataLink = [
                        'http://ad-emea.doubleclick.net/adj/N6705.309581.LAMODA.RU1/B5807564.309;sz=590x508;ord=',
                        'http://ad-emea.doubleclick.net/adj/N6705.309581.LAMODA.RU1/B5807564.310;sz=590x508;ord=',
                        'http://ad-emea.doubleclick.net/adj/N6705.309581.LAMODA.RU1/B5807564.308;sz=590x508;ord='
                    ];
            $(function(){
                $('#slides_container').bannerWriter({
                    data: dataLink,
                    onComplete: function(element){
                        element.find('a').prop('target','_self');
                        element.parent().slides({
                            play: 5000,
                            pause: 2500,
                            paginationClass: 'pgn',
                            generateNextPrev: true,
                            hoverPause: true
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        })();
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Подключить `jQuery` как минимум:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

а дальше разбираться с кодом и разбираться

советую выбрать слайдер отсюда [Эффектные слайд-шоу и фото-галереи jQuery](http://shurawi.blogspot.com/2012/02/jeffektnye-slajd-shou-i-foto-galerei.html) , проблем меньше будет и функции все задокументированы

Comment: хотелось бы слайдер тот, что на ламоде скопировать. 

jquery  там подключен по этой ссылке: lamoda.ru/tstatic/js/libs.js?v=923658779c7df00e14c8d1dda07c4c56

а вот почему не фурычит не понятно(((

Comment: пробовал так подключать:

 <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var timestamp = new Date().getTime(),
                   dataLink.splice(0,0,'<div><a href="/rasprodazha/"><img src="//lmcdn.ru/media/banner/HP_mnogo_MZ.jpg" alt="mnogo.ru" /></a></div>');

Comment: .

    $(function(){
    $('#slides_container').bannerWriter({
    data: dataLink,
                    onComplete: function(element){
                        element.find('a').prop('target','_self');
                        element.parent().slides({
                            play: 5000,
                            pause: 2500,
                            paginationClass: 'pgn',
                            generateNextPrev: true,
                            hoverPause: true
                        });
                    }
                });
            });


        })();
    </script>

Comment: но тоже безрезультатно, кто что думает? как можно решить проблему?

Comment: любой из тех скриптов можно подогнать под ламоду, для этого надо подогнать настройки и немного с кодом повозится. nivoslider тот же. вот урок по подгонке слайдера h.t.t.p://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=1094   а возня с чужим слайдером неблагодарная задача...
P.S.: на google chrome у меня не показывает слайдер на ламоде, есть над чем задуматься